# Import qgis.core in Azure Functions

Tags: qgis, api, qgis.core

Do any of you know if you can use qgis.core in Azure Functions to build an API?

We mainly work with Python code, where we use functions that depend on qgis.core. In Azure Functions you can easily use libraries that are pip install compatible, but qgis.core is not. QGIS is open source so there should be a way right?

Steps tried (failed):

1. Virtual machine on Azure
2. Include QGIS as a dependency when deploying a function via VSC:
3. Directly via installation (copy folders with Python dependency and include them)
4. Via a Conda installation in a virtual environment (provide this environment when deploying)
5. Via Docker